# Proving that the free sum of two Polyhedra is a Polyhedra

Tags: geometry, polyhedra, polytopes

For definitions and reference, we are working from Guenter Ziegler's *Lectures on Polytopes.*

We define the free sum as follows. Given two polyhedra $P, Q \in \mathbb{R}^d$, the free sum $P \bigoplus Q = \text{ conv }(P \cup Q)$.

Here are my thoughts so far:

One definition of polyhedra is that we have some finite set of points $V_1$ and some finite list of vectors $Y_1$ such that $P = \text{ conv }(V_1) + \text{ cone }(Y_1)$. Similarly, $Q = \text{ conv }(V_2) + \text{ cone }(Y_2)$.

So, $$\text{ conv }(P \cup Q) = \text{ conv }((\text{ conv }(V_1) + \text{ cone }(Y_1)) \cup (\text{ conv }(V_2) + \text{ cone }(Y_2)))$$

I'd like to show that this can somehow reduce to our previous definition, so $P \bigoplus Q = \text{ conv }(V) + \text{ cone }(Y)$ for some finite $V,Y$.

But maybe this is not a good direction to go in proving this.

Comment: This may help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_polytope#Intersection_of_half-spaces

Comment: If, in a plainer way, you define a polyhedron as the convex hull of some finite set of points, you are done !

Comment: @JeanMarie In our class, I don't think we define polyhedra in this way. A polyhedra is a potentially unbounded intersection of closed halfspaces; is there an equivalent V-description for this?

Comment: I had in mind **bounded** polyhedra, but you are right : in order to include unbounded polyhedra, you have to take the definition you just gave.

Comment: Usually the $free\ sum$ of 2 polytopes rather is being defined as $conv((P,0)\cup (0,Q))$ instead. That one then is also known as the $tegum\ product$. Your definition however comes down to what I'd call the $tegum\ sum$. Cf. to https://bendwavy.org/klitzing/explain/product.htm#orthoplex